# How to get cookies and use them for other requests like POST ( iOS )?

Tags: iphone, ios, cookies

My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538782/how-to-remain-logged-in-until-user-decides-to-logout/) was about the problem that I have to login each time for doing web services like posting a link or uploading a picture. Philipe answered that I have to use cookies instead of login process for each request. I found this method for getting cookies:

```
- (void)getCookies {

    NSHTTPURLResponse * response;
    NSError * error;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request;

    request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://MyWebsite.com/login.php"]
                                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                        timeoutInterval:120];
    NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
    NSArray * all = [NSHTTPCookie cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:[response allHeaderFields] forURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://MyWebsite.com/login.php"]];
    NSLog(@"%d", all.count);

    for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in all) {
        NSLog(@"Name: %@ : Value: %@", cookie.name, cookie.value);
        NSLog(@"Comment: %@ : CommentURL: %@", cookie.comment, cookie.commentURL);
        NSLog(@"Domain: %@ : ExpiresDate: %@", cookie.domain, cookie.expiresDate);
        NSLog(@"isHTTPOnly: %c : isSecure: %c", cookie.isHTTPOnly, cookie.isSecure);
        NSLog(@"isSessionOnly: %c : path: %@", cookie.isSessionOnly, cookie.path);
        NSLog(@"portList: %@ : properties: %@", cookie.portList, cookie.properties);
        NSLog(@"version: %u", cookie.version);
    }
}
```

I also found this code to use these cookies, but I'm not sure how to use it:

```
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookies];
```

Here is my method for POSTing, I am using RestKit API:

```
- (IBAction)addLinkPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

        [RKClient clientWithBaseURLString:@"http://MyWebsite.com"];

        NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                self.linkField.text, @"url",
                                self.linkTitleField.text, @"title",
                                self.linkSummaryField.text, @"summary",
                                nil];

        RKRequest *request = [[RKClient sharedClient] post:@"/send_link.php" params:params delegate:self];
        [request setUserData:@"sendLink"];   
}
```

**Question:** Which property of cookies should I store to use it for login information and where should I put it in my code?

Answer (score 0):

```
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```